# How to prevent entering non numeric symbols and numbers out of range in InputNumber in Form.Item ant

Tags: reactjs, antd

I tried to handle it in `onChange` through controlled input.

Tried to handle it in `formatter` and in `parser` but invalid values doesn't trigger it, despite the fact that symbols entering in input.

Tried to set value in this input by `setFieldsValue` method that provided by `useForm` hook.

Tried to set `type="number"`

Nothing of this works while `InputNumber` is inside `Form.Item`. [Link to Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-forked-2dw5qm)

Please help. How I can resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following example.

Following code will allow user to enter only the numbers

App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { InputNumber, Form } from 'antd';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Form>
      <Form.Item name="input-with-type">
        <InputNumber
          type="number"
          min={0}
          max={9999.99}
          onKeyDown={(event) => {
            const re = /^[0-9\b]+$/;
            if (!re.test(event.key) && event.key !== 'Backspace') {
              event.preventDefault();
            }
          }}
        />
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Note**: you can change the regex expression according to your requirements